# Normal back buffer + render to depth texture in OpenGL (FBOs)

Tags: opengl, fbo

Here's the situation: I have a texture containing some depth values.  I want to render some geometry using that texture as the depth buffer, **but I want the color to be written to the normal framebuffer** (i.e., the window's framebuffer).

How do I do this?  I tried creating an FBO and only binding a depth texture to it (GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT) but that didn't work; none of the colors showed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. The FBO you are rendering to may be either a main framebuffer or an off-screen one. You can't mix them in any way.

Instead, I would suggest you to render to a color renderbuffer and then do a simple blitting operation into the main framebuffer.

Edit-1.

Alternatively, if you already have depth in the main FB, you can first blit your depth and then render to a main FB, thus saving video memory on the additional color renderbuffer.

P.S. Blitting is done via `glBlitFramebuffer`. In order to make it work you should setup `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`, `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` and glDrawBuffer() for each of them.

Comment: Rendering in the main/window framebuffer is masked to only the visible parts of the window, i.e. where the window is occluded no contents are written to the main/window framebuffer. If the system uses a compositing desktop (XComposite/Copmiz, Windows Vista/7 Aero) no window occlusion happens, but if there's no compositing or it is disabled this masking happens.